# the transmission and reception block for the hackRF does not work Windows 11

Tags: gnuradio

Previously, I used the **"Osmocom sink"** and **"Osmocom Source"** blocks, but after updating the GNU radio to version 3.9.4, these blocks were gone. As far as I understand, now it has been replaced by **"Soapy HackRF sink"**, but I cannot start the transmitter, an error pops up:

```
stream_args, tune_args, settings)
RuntimeError: SoapySDR::Device::make() no match
Done (return code 1)"
```

[image]
I downloaded the program here: https://www.castle.cloud/gnuradio-for-windows/download/

Comment: since the osmocom blocks are not *part* of GNU Radio, you'd need to build/install them yourself after updating. But yes, Soapy is the modern alternative to these.

Comment: "an error pops up" <-- That error is very likely very important, and without knowing that error, I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: i added error text at the top

Comment: that isn't the full error. The erorr starts with "Traceback:"!

Comment: But I think this might be enough to make an educated guess :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from the error message, this is SoapySDR telling you that,

> hey, everything is alright up to here, but now you're asking me to look for a device with a driver I haven't heard about.

The solution is luckily simple:

Just build and install the Soapysdr-hackrf plugin. I don't know the installation source you're using, but I guess it includes a file `include/SoapySDR/Device.hpp` and all the other header files. (otherwise including gr-soapysdr would be very useless – they don't ship a single SoapySDR driver themselves according to their website.) 
With these headers, you can easily build the [SoapySDR-hackrf](https://github.com/pothosware/SoapyHackRF) driver plugin.

I don't know whether the binary installer includes any build tools – and that might make this endeavour much harder than just to follow the official [GNU Radio Conda Installation](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/CondaInstall) Guide (recommended by the  GNU Radio community ourselves to get it on Windows):

- just download and install [radioconda](https://github.com/ryanvolz/radioconda).
- After installation, make sure you can run the "Conda prompt" from the "radio conda" start menu entry. There, make sure `gnuradio-companion`<kbd>↵</kbd> starts GNU Radio companion. If that works, in said Prompt:
- Execute the following two lines:

```
# Attention: this is the way to get the HackRF soapy module on *Windows only* 
# at the time of writing, 2022-01-02. If you're not on windows, or if some 
# time has passed since then, please consult
# https://anaconda.org/search?q=soapysdr-module-hackrf
# to see wether there's e.g a `conda-forge / soapysdr-module-hackrf` package
# available by now.
conda config --env --add channels delichon
conda install -c delichon soapysdr-module-hackrf
```

(As you might notice above, this is from a non-official conda source, "delichon"; it would be better if there was official packaging for these, so that it's installable with less complication. I know great scott gadgets [is aware of these packages](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/hackrf/issues/875), and they're cool folks.)